# retrieve data from pandas dataframe if it doesn't cooccur in previous column

Tags: pandas, filtering

I have a pandas dataframe full of strings, and some strings are found in 2 or more consecutive columns.  I want to retrieve only those instances of strings that are not also found in the previous column.  I also want to have the dataframe column of each such string instance.

So, if my dataframe were the following

```
      A    B    C    D
a    'x'  'a'  'r'   'a'
b    'y'  'y'  'b'   'b'
c    'z'  'x'  'x'   'y'
```

I want the following information (not neccesarily in list or tuple format).

```
    [('x',A), ('y', A), ('z', A), ('a', B), ('r',C), ('b',C), ('a',D), ('y',D)]
```

I don't really care about the format for the output.  The only requirement is that the output be in a format in which I can quickly reference each retrieved string and its column. Speed here is my priority, as I am dealing with many columns, each one being 20 rows long.

Any ideas regarding the fastest way to accomplish this? Thanks! - Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. First use `df.T != df.T.shift(1)` to determine whether the column `i` has the same value of column `i-1`. And then a list comprehension to produce the desired output.

```
mask = (df.T != df.T.shift(1)).T
mask

      A      B      C      D
a  True   True   True   True
b  True  False   True  False
c  True   True  False   True

[ (m,n) for m, n in df[mask].stack().reset_index(level=1).values]

# output
[('A', 'x'),
 ('B', 'a'),
 ('C', 'r'),
 ('D', 'a'),
 ('A', 'y'),
 ('C', 'b'),
 ('A', 'z'),
 ('B', 'x'),
 ('D', 'y')]
```